# Is there a LaTeX package that lets me explicitely show indentation on paragraphs?

Tags: packages, indentation, paragraphs

I'm looking for the following sort of effect in my document:

[image]

Or something like this:

[image: Does anybody read me? I'm lonely. :(]

Is there a package that lets me do this?

Comment: `\begin{itemize}`?

Comment: `\lstset{showtabs=true,tab=\rightarrowfill}` from package [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) is close.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The below code makes tabs active and increments a counter every time one is encountered. At the beginning of a paragraph, a paragraph hook is added that removes the box that is inserted by an indentation, checks the depth of the indentation, sets `\leftskip` to the depth times `\parindent`, and then adds a arrow of the appropriate width to the left.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{everyhook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcount\indentdepth
\newdimen\savedleftskip
\catcode`\^^I\active
\newenvironment{tabs}{%
    \savedleftskip=\leftskip
    \catcode`\^^I\active
    \def^^I{%
        \ifhmode
            \par
        \fi
        \advance\indentdepth by1
    }%
    \PushPreHook{par}{%
        {\setbox0\lastbox}% kill the indent
        \ifnum\indentdepth>0
            \leftskip\dimexpr\savedleftskip+\parindent*\indentdepth\relax
            \llap{\hbox to\leftskip{\rightarrowfill}}%
        \fi
    }%
    \def\par{%
        \endgraf
        \indentdepth=0
        \leftskip=\savedleftskip
    }%
    \indentdepth=0
}{%
    \par
    \PopPreHook{par}%
}
\catcode`^^I10
\begin{document}
\begin{tabs}
No indent on the text here.
        One indent.
                Two indent.
                More.
                Even More.
                Blah.
        Back to one indent.

Back to no indent.
        \lipsum[1]
                \lipsum[2]
\end{tabs}
\end{document}
```

Note that there is a blank line before `Back to no indent`. The reason for this is that unless TeX pays attention to the end of lines (e.g., by using `\obeylines`), there's no way to distinguish end of line from a space. Any of the indented material can be distinguished because the tab character causes the paragraph to end.

If you copy and paste this code, it's important that you change the 8 space indentation in the use of the `tabs` environment into actual "hard" tabs.

Here's a second way to do it that looks like your second example. Here, a newline starts a new line in the output. Any line that is taller than a `\strut` will not have the appropriate rule drawn in front of it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{everyhook}
\newdimen\tabwidth
\newcount\indentdepth
\tabwidth=\parindent
\catcode`\^^I\active
\newenvironment{tabs}{%
    \catcode`\^^I\active
    \def^^I{\advance\indentdepth by1}%
    \def\par{\endgraf\indentdepth=0}%
    \PushPreHook{par}{%
        \ifnum\indentdepth>0
            \hbox to\dimexpr\tabwidth*\indentdepth{%
                \hfill\vrule height\ht\strutbox depth\dp\strutbox\ %
            }%
        \fi
    }%
    \parindent=0pt
    \obeylines
    \indentdepth=0
}{%
    \PopPreHook{par}%
}
\catcode`\^^I10
\begin{document}
\begin{tabs}
No indent on the text here.
        One indent.
                Two indent.
                More
                Even More.
                Blah.
        Back to one indent.
Back to no indent.
\end{tabs}
\end{document}
```

Again, be sure to add the tabs back in.